# compile error when referencing other project's header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have 2 projects in my solution:

win32 console application
.lib project

.lib project uses third party .lib and header. I added their paths and names in .lib project's properties. it compiles ok and .lib file is generated ok too.

Now win32 project want to call the other project's functions.
So in win 32 application, I added other project's .lib and other project's header files.

Now when I compile the win 32 console application project, it gives me an error pointing to a header file in my .lib project and says that headerfile of the other project cant locate the third party's header in its include statement.

how to fix it.

In the .lib project properties, c/C++->General->"Additional Include Directories" I added third party's .h folder path. $(SolutionDir)\include\third_party

In the .lib project properties, Librarian->General->"Additional Dependencies"  I added third party's .lib file path.  $(SolutionDir)\lib\thirdpartyprocessor.lib

It compiled ok.

Now win 32 project properties ->C/C++->General->ADditional Include Directories. I added the other .lib project's .h file path  path $(SolutionDir)\MyProcessor

win 32 project properties ->Linker->General->AdditionalLibrary Directories, I added path to my other project's .lib file. $(OutDir)

win 32 project properties ->Linker->Input, I added my other project's .lib file name. "MyProcessor.lib" which exists in the $(OutDir) as I specified in Linker->General->Additional Directories

Now when I reference .h file of my .lib project from win32 application, it complains the .h file of .lib project that I am referencing dont know the third party .h it includes.

I then also added the third party .lib and header files in win32 project, just like  I added my other project's lib, but even that did not fix it.

Comment: Make sure you added the path of the third party headers to your additional include folders for your project. If those headers include other files (and folders are specified in the includes) make sure that the folder structure is kept.

Comment: Outside of that we can't really help any further since you are not being specific.

Comment: I added specific details.